# Directories with random numbers as foldername being created that contain .ser files

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, tld

So in our weblogic 10.3 server there are folders being generated with random names (such as "7nxxd", "tpy16q"). Inside each of these is the same subdirectory structure:

```
<randomfilename>/.tld_cache/WEB-INF/tld/
                                        c.tld/
                                        fn.tld/
                                        spring-form.tld/
                                        fmt.tld/
                                        spring.tld/
                                        tiles-jsp.tld/
```

Each of these directories has 2 files: crc.ser and des.ser.

Why are these files being created? Is there a way to specify the directory that they get written to besides the random name?

Answer (score 1):

JavaEE servers will frequently generate temporary working directories to hold various items, such as cahced descriptors, compiled JSPs, etc.

You can probably influence where it puts them, but that's server-specific. You'll need to read up on your server and find out how to do that.