# TLD cache location in Weblogic 10.3?

Tags: jsp, weblogic-10.x, tld

In my Weblogic 10.3 instance, the TLD cache files are being saved into a randomly named directory (such as "7nxxd", "tpy16q"). Is there any way to specify the location these files go into, as opposed to it being random? In the [OC4J to weblogic conversion doc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15523_01/upgrade.1111/e10126/deploy_descriptors_ref2.htm), the jsp-cache-directory setting is described that "unlike the jsp-cache-directory configuration in OC4J, this directory is not relevant for TLDs," and later on that "Unlike OC4J, TLD caching cannot be disabled with a deployment descriptor element."

I dont want to disable TLD caching, I just want to specify where the cache goes! Is there a way to do this? All of the documentation that I can find points to the old OC4J documentation and not the new weblogic docs.

Comment: I've also been looking for the same since I came across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696275/directories-with-random-numbers-as-foldername-being-created-that-contain-ser-fil but not foudn the solution yet.

Comment: Yeah, that was my previous question, before I knew the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

This is relevant to 2 known Oracle Weblogic Bugs:

1. 12592572 : RANDOM DIRECTORIES GET CREATED UNDER THE DOMAIN DIRECTORY WHEN DEPLOYING 
   WEBAPP
2. 10052682 : TLD CACHE IS CREATED UNDER DOMAIN ROOT DIRECTORY

There are availbale patches for download if you have Oracle Support